# getline() not opening text file

Tags: c++, codeblocks, getline

Hi I am currently using CodeBlocks 13.12 on OSX.

I am trying to open the following .txt file

line 1
line 2
line 3

My code is just:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<'\n';
    std::string line;
    ifstream myfile("textex.txt");
    if(myfile.is_open())
        cout << "File is open";
    else
        cout << "File not open";

    cout<<'\n';
    return 0;
}
```

I have also included the file in the project folder and have tried linking it and compiling it.

When I run the code, it displays"File not open" and I'm not sure why? 
I'm new to c++, can someone please explain why this isn't working?

Comment: Linking and compiling an arbitrary .txt file? Programming by guessing doesn't work mate :)

Comment: Use [getcwd()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getcwd.html) to display what directory the application thinks it is running in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
    ifstream myfile("textex.txt");
```

Try

```
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("/Users/name/Code/textex.txt"); // Use the full path
```

Answer (score 1):

Possibly because the project folder is not set as the working directory. Try specifying the full path.

Comment: I tried changing it to `ifstream myfile("/Users/name/Code/textex.txt");` but it still outputs "File not open"

Answer (score 0):

Try typing the full path of the file instead of just the file name.
Tell me what happens then.

On another note but unrelated, since you are using the "using namespace" directive, you may as well omit std:: from string just like you did with cin and cout. It is not a big deal, just the look of the code.

Comment: I tried changing it to ifstream myfile("/Users/name/Code/textex.txt"); but it still outputs "File not open"

Comment: I do not know man.
I dont have OSX so I dont know if that is the right way to write the path.

Comment: I have an idea try creating an output file and then reopen it as input. The program should create it in a location it can read from.

`ofstream myout("test.txt");
myout << "test";
myout.close();

ifstream myfile("test.txt");`

then write the same if statement.

I know I didnt test if the output file is open but just say it opens correctly for now.

Answer (score 0):

When you run your program from Code::Blocks it runs on project folder so your text file must be in your project folder, otherwise text file must be in the folder where your executable is.